# How to pass data in jqPlot meter gauge?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jqplot

I' m using this [plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/meterGauge.php)

There's a gauge on my page:

```
s1 = [50000];

   plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4',[s1],{
     seriesDefaults: {
       renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
       rendererOptions: {
           label: 'Metric Tons per Year',
           labelPosition: 'bottom',
           labelHeightAdjust: -5,
           intervalOuterRadius: 85,
           ticks: [10000, 30000, 50000, 70000],
           intervals:[22000, 55000, 70000],
           intervalColors:['#66cc66', '#E7E658', '#cc6666']
       }
     }
 });
```

I want the next scenario: user enters a number in input, presses submit and arrow shows this value on gauge. So, I've made an input and added this code right above the gauge code:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var data = $("#test").val();
  s1 = [data];
  console.log(s1);
  return s1;
});
```

Console outputs value, but how to make the arrow show this value? Cannot find any method for this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line in your button click function to dynamically update the value:

```
 plot.series[0].data[0] = [1, newValue];
```

then you need to call `replot()` to redraw the gauge:

```
plot.replot();
```

The complete click function is:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var newValue = $("#test").val();
  plot.series[0].data[0] = [1, newValue];
  plot.replot();
  return s1;
});
```

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4vs8vz/5/) shows a working demo. Type a value into the text box and click "Change Value" to update the gauge.